# display specific custom fields

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I have few custom field assigned for each post, like: 
"Club" with value "club1" 
"Date" with value "date1"
and so on...

Now, I want to display from all the custom fields just those 2 " club" and "date".

This is my markup :

```
                    <div class="meta-container"><?php the_meta(); ?></div>
```

The problem with this, is that is retrieving all the custom fields and I don't want this. 
I was thinking to add css psedoselector like nth:child(n)  but I'm sure that I can do this with this function. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) twice (Ref to your [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96008/problem-retrieving-specific-custom-meta)):

```
<?php
  echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'club', true ); 
  echo '<br />';
  echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'date', true ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, one of your tags is exactly what you need! You're looking for WordPress' get_post_meta function: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Within the loop, it would look something like this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Club', true); ?>
```

Comment: I've tried also this, but is not working, now it doesn't display anything.

Comment: My bad, it was a cache problem, it's working but I can not retrieve two values: I've tried this: `<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'CLUB','DATES', true); ?>`